# How to click buttons in selenium? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button

So there's this button with no name tag so I couldn't use find_element_by_name() method.
Here is the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="send message" onclick="submitForm()">
```

I already tried

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_name("send message")
```

and it returns nothing.

How do I get the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with xpath

```py
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='send message']")[0]
login_button.click()
```

If this xpath doesn't work I would recommend you to get xpath by your self.
To get xpath; 
open `inspect element` (`ctrl+shift+c`)

then hover your mouse to the button on the webpage then you will see highlight at the right (or bottom) a node will be highlighted click on the webpage and node will be selected in inspect element. 
Right click the node on inspect element and go to `copy >` then press on `xpath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching by xpath and the type submit like this:

```
login_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
```